# How to improve the sql containing IN with Split function in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have a query which will operate on on millions of record. Now, I have this in my WHERE clause,

```
WHERE Status IN (SELECT VALUE FROM SPLIT(@Status,','))
```

Clearly, *'SELECT VALUE FROM SPLIT(@Status,',')'* will be operate on every row. I need to improve this.

Comment: "Clearly, 'SELECT VALUE FROM SPLIT(@Status,',')' will be operate on every row." --- why do you think so?

Comment: because it is in my WHERE clause. So, every selection will check this.

Comment: IIRC `SPLIT` will create a temp table. Have a look [here](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do you current solution or compare its performance with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN SPLIT(@Status,',') B
ON A.Status = B.Value
```

Comment: Yup, INNER JOIN is helping me. But whey you say 'do you current solution'?

Comment: @user960567: because there is a chance that optimizer performs both in very similar way

Answer (score 1):

How anout placing the results from the `SPLIT` function in a `table variable/temp table` first and then doing an `INNER JOIN` on this rather?

Comment: temp table does not help but inner join does

Answer (score 1):

Unpack you string to a temp table and use that in your query instead. Having an index on the field in the temp table should help.

```
create table #Split (Value varchar(10) primary key)

insert into #Split(Value)
select distinct Value
from SPLIT(@Status, ',')

select SomeCol
from YourTable
where Status in (select Value from #Split)

drop table #Split
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not help to improve my query.